# Is this a correct implementation on circular linked list (Queue)?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code on circular queue using linked list.
I stumbled to a problem where i don't exactly know if this is the correct implementation of circular queue using linked list.
Here is the code that i wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} *rear,*front,*temp,*newNode;

void create()
{
    front = rear = NULL;
}

void enqueue(int data)
{
    newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode -> data = data;
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL)
        front = rear = newNode;
    else
    {
        rear -> next = newNode;
        rear = newNode;
    }
    rear -> next = front;
}

int dequeue()
{
    int x;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (front == rear)
    {
        x = front->data;
        delete front;
        front = rear = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = front;
        x = temp -> data;
        front = front -> next;

        rear -> next = front;
        delete temp;
    }
    return x;
}


int empty()
{
    if(front == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}


void display()
{
    node *temp = front;
    printf("\nCIRCULAR QUEUE : ");
    do
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }while (temp != front);
}

int main()
{
    int num,choice;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\nQUEUE OPERATIONS\n\n1.ENQUEUE\n2.DEQUEUE\n3.DISPLAY\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter item : ");
                scanf("%d",&num);
                enqueue(num);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!(empty()))
                    printf("\nDequeued element : %d",dequeue());
                else
                    printf("\nEMPTY QUEUE\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                display();
                break;
            default: exit(0);
        }}
    return 0;
}
```

When i enqueue integers to the program it seems to run the queue program just fine. Then i dequeued 2 numbers and the first 2 numbers was deleted. Then i inserted 2 more numbers, but when i displayed the numbers, the recently inserted numbers got displayed in the back, not at the front.

Is there a solution? or is this just the correct implementation of circular queue using linked list?

Comment: Getting displayed in the back is quite natural for the new numbers because you are adding numbers to back and removing numbers from front.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is wrong.

Firstly, in the function `dequeue()`, you used `delete front;` and `delete temp;`.
This is an invaild syntax in C. Also, even if this code were C++, this is bad because the buffer is allocated via `malloc()`. You will have to use `free(front);` and `free(temp);` instead.

Secondly, you didn't check if the queue is empty in the `display()` function. Also the call of `display()` is not guarded with `empty()` check unlike it is done for `dequeue()` function. `NULL` will be dereferenced and Segmentation Fault may happen when `display()` is called when the queue is empty.

Also note that you should check the return values of `scanf()` to check if it actually read data (or didn't read, reaching at EOF or invalid input) and casting result of `malloc()` is [discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).